# Ionic loading not working

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm working on an ionic app. 
I want to show a loading symbol while fetching data. So I used the following code:

```
function showLoading() {
    console.log("Loading")
    $ionicLoading.show({
        content: 'Loading',
        animation: 'fade-in',
        showBackdrop: true,
        maxWidth: 200,
        showDelay: 0
    });
};

function hideLoading(){
    console.log("hide loading")
    $ionicLoading.hide();
};
```

but it is still not working.

Comment: WHAT is not working? What's the issue/error ?

Comment: Sorry jonrsharpe. i rectified the issue by own. thanks for your response.

Comment: Maybe you could share the resolving of the issue. It could help some people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `$scope` variable in AngularJs functions.

```
$scope.showLoading = function () {

    console.log("Loading");

    $ionicLoading.show({
        content: 'Loading',
        animation: 'fade-in',
        showBackdrop: true,
        maxWidth: 200,
        showDelay: 0
    });

};

$scope.hideLoading = function () {
    console.log("hide loading");
    $ionicLoading.hide();
};
```